# How to show dot badge instead of counter badge in app launcher icon?

Tags: flutter, notifications, badge, flutter-local-notification

I am using `flutter_local_notifications: ^9.7.0` to show notification and that's really nice package, using that package I am available to get badge with icon "1" when notification pops up. What I would like to ask.. instead of showing "1" badge, I would like to show dot badge. Is there a way to do that using `flutter_local_notifications` or any other package ?

Comment: what kind of badge are you looking for.....?

Comment: I would like to show dot badge on icon app without number @JintoJoseph

Comment: @JintoJoseph what I mean is showing the badge on the icon launcher app not inside the app

Comment: @JintoJoseph that's different, I would like to show dot only without number or counter on the badge

Answer (score 0):

Notification Badges are Platform's entity & unfortunately, you can not do anything to change it.

As mentioned in Android [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges)

> These dots appear by default in launcher apps that support them and there's nothing your app needs to do.